# How to convert 'unsigned long' to string in java

Tags: java, long-integer

it is clear that java does not have 'unsigned long' type, while we can use long to store a unsigned data. Then how can I convert it to a String or just print it in a 'unsigned' manner?

Comment: what do you mean "print it in a unsigned manner" ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use BigInteger unfortunately, or write your own routine.

Here is an [Unsigned](https://code.google.com/p/java-unsigned/source/browse/trunk/unsigned/src/main/java/com/google/code/unsigned/Unsigned.java?r=6) class which helps with these workarounds

```
private static final BigInteger BI_2_64 = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(64);

public static String asString(long l) {
    return l >= 0 ? String.valueOf(l) : toBigInteger(l).toString();
}

public static BigInteger toBigInteger(long l) {
    final BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(l);
    return l >= 0 ? bi : bi.add(BI_2_64);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25248688/2032064) on SO, there is a method for that starting with Java 8:

```
System.out.println(Long.toUnsignedString(Long.MAX_VALUE)); // 9223372036854775807
System.out.println(Long.toUnsignedString(Long.MIN_VALUE)); // 9223372036854775808
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you use third-party libraries?  Guava's [`UnsignedLongs.toString(long)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedLongs.html#toString%28long%29) does this.

Answer (score 0):

```
long quot = (number >>> 1) / 5L; // get all digits except last one
long rem = number - quot * 10L; // get last digit with overflow trick
String out = Long.toString(quot) + rem;
```

Comment: This is actually the same algorithm used by Java 8's [`Long.toUnsignedString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#toUnsignedString(long)).