# Reverse digits of an integer

Tags: algorithm

how to reverse a number?

Example1: x = 123, return 321
Example2: x = -123, return -321

this is my answer:

```
public int reverse(int x) {
    int result = 0;
    while(x != 0){
        result = result * 10 + x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

but when I input 1534236469 , it will output 1056389759 , this is wrong. what do you think about my program? thanks.

Comment: unless int is required use string as input. 1. check for the minus sign remove if if present. 2. call string.reverse() 3. add minus sign back if it was removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write  x >0 (doesn't matter though )also after that you have to consider negative numbers , I made that change to your logic as follows (Also use long long to avoid overflow):

```
      long long reverse(long long x)
      {

           int sign = 1;
           long long ans=0;
           if(x < 0)
             sign = -1;
           x = abs(x);
           while(x > 0)
           {
               ans *= 10;
               ans += x%10;
               x /=10;
           }
           return ans*sign;
      }
```

Comment: The OP's problem case was a positive number.  For positive numbers, your code looks identical to his. Does it produce the correct result on `x=1534236469` ?

Comment: @jez also as OP gave in example a negative number I covered that case

Comment: Indeed, your solution is correct. It would be helpful if however you pointed out what the difference between yours and the OP's code is. Rather than just given them code with no annotation (you fixed the while bug, and the sign bug).

Comment: David K has got the answer

Comment: @aruisdante sorry wrote the answer in haste , will do so. will make an edit. thanks

Comment: It also still doesn't account for numbers > maximal size of `int`. If that's a requirement, should use `long` etc (doesn't pass the OP's example case).

Comment: @JasonNi I pointed your mistakes and took aruisdantes advice to edit my answe have a look

Comment: if(x < 0)  sign = -1;  x = abs(x); can be if (x<0) { sign = -1;x=-x; }

Comment: can "long long" work in java? I use your code in java , compile error shows up

Comment: @JasonNi, in java use BigInteger

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508630/java-equivalent-of-unsigned-long-long no its for C++ you use long , if its bigger then use strings or BigInteger

Comment: how do I catch the overflow, if overflow it returns 0

Comment: @JasonNi not familiar how it is done in Java, but as everyone else suggested you could use big integer to avoid it

Answer (score 5):

One reason your program cannot give the right answer is that you
store `result` in an `int` but you expect to be able to 
reverse the number 1534236469.
The correct answer would be 9646324351,
but that number is greater than the largest possible value of an `int`
so you end up with something else.
Try `long long` or try using input with no more than 9 digits.

---

**Followup:**
I suggested `long long` because that will fairly reliably give you
an 8-byte integer. You may also get 8 bytes in a `long`, depending on
where you are building your code, 
but Visual C++ on 32-bit Windows (for example) will
give you only 4 bytes. Possibly the 4-byte long will go the way of the 2-byte int soon enough, but at this point in time some of us still have to deal with it.

Comment: yes, you are right, I know the number is over the int type, so how to correct it?

Comment: use `long` or equivalent. It still won't make your code work for negative nubmers however.

Comment: negative numbers should be work by this method. only if the number do not over the int type

Comment: Look at sasha's answer, which has an idea for dealing with negative numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Jason,
You should just change the type from int to long.

```
   public long  reverse(long x)
    {
        long result = 0;
        while (x != 0)
        {
            result = result * 10 + x % 10;
            x = x / 10;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: this will not work for a negative number, which is part of the OP's input examples.

Comment: It also depends on the environment where you run. g++ on 64-bit linux will give you 8 bytes to a `long`, Visual C++ on Win32 will give you 4 bytes.

Comment: if the input number over the long type, I think it should be wrong. how do I catch the overflow, if overflow it returns 0

Comment: Jason , may you please explain your issue more?

Comment: @Fery My issue is when I input 1534236469 , then the result should be 9646324351, but this is overflow for int. so how can I catch the overflow and return 0. thanks.

Comment: So, you need a program to reverse digits of positive and negative integer number and if the input overflows the integer type, 0 should be returned. Am I right?And and we are assuming the int data type you are working with is a 32-bit signed.

Comment: @JasonNi: What is the environment you use?

Comment: @aruisdante : because of definition of % in C#.net, the method works for negative numbers, if you are in same IDE. Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx):

Comment: Indeed, but the `%` operator behaves differently depending on language. Since they don't specify, it's probably unsafe to assume that `%` will behave as expected for negative values, especially since the independent fix is relatively straight forwards.

Comment: @Fery I'm using Intellij for Java

Comment: @JasonNi Check [this link](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/NUM00-J.+Detect+or+prevent+integer+overflow) out.

Answer (score 1):

How about convert to string and reverse? Quite simple:

```
   int reverseDigits(int x) {
      String s = Integer.toString(x);
      for (int i = 0; i < s.length() / 2; i++) {
        char t = s[i];
        s[i] = s[s.length() - i - 1];
        s[s.length() - i - 1] = t;
      }
      return Integer.parseInteger(s); // subject to overflow
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

can use long type to store the result

```
public int reverse(int x) {
    long result = 0;
    while (x != 0) {
        result = result * 10 + x % 10;
        x /= 10;
    }
    if (result > Integer.MAX_VALUE || result < Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        return 0;
    return (int)result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a question posted on Leetcode and it gives a wrong answer expecting a 0. The clue is that before returning the reversed integer we have to check if it does not exceed the limit of a 32-bit int ie 2^31-1.

Code in Python 3:

```
class Solution:
def reverse(self, x: int) -> int:
    s=[]
    rev=0
    neg=False
    if x==0:
        return 0
    if x<0:
        x=x* -1
        neg=True
    while x:
        s.append(x%10)
        x=int(x/10)
    i=len(s)
    j=0
    while i:
        rev=rev+s[j]*10**(i-1)
        i=i-1
        j=j+1
    if(rev>2**31-1):
        return 0
    return rev * -1 if neg else rev
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do:

```
while (x)
  print x%10
  x /= 10
```

with a double sign conversion if the value of x is originally negative, to avoid the question of what mod a -ve number is.

Answer (score 0):

You are using int for storing the number whereas number is out of range of int. You have tagged algorithm in this question. So, better way would be by using link list. You can google more about it. There are lot of algorithms for reversing a link list.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version of Schultz9999's answer:

```
int reverseDigits(int x) {
  String s = Integer.toString(x);
  s=new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();
  return Integer.parseInt(s); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the python code of reverse number::

```
n=int(input('Enter the number:'))
r=0

while (n!=0):        
    remainder=n%10
    r=remainder+(r*10)
    n=n//10       

print('Reverse order is %d'%r)
```

Answer (score 0):

A compact Python solution is

```
reverse = int(str(number)[::-1])
```

If negative numbers are a possibility, then

```
num = abs(number)          # absolute value of the number
rev = int(str(num)[::-1])  # reverse the number
reverse = -rev             # negate the reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS I wrote it in this way

```
function reverseNumber(n) {
  const reversed = n
    .toString()
    .split('')
    .reverse()
    .join('');

  return parseInt(reversed) * Math.sign(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reverse Integer In JavaScript | Accepted LeetCode solution | Memory efficient**

If reversing the number causes the value to go outside the signed 32-bit integer range [-2^31, 2^31 - 1], then returned 0.

*Intuition*:
First converted the integer to a string which is much easy to reverse and check characters.

*Approach*:
Converted number to string.
Checked for 1st character negative value.
Spliced (-) and stored if any which is concat in the last.
Then reversed the string without (-).

```
    var reverse = function(x) {
    x= x.toString();
    let s = Number(x[0]) ? '' : x[0],reverse='';
    if(s) { //If x= -123 && here s='-'
        x =x.substring(1) // removing '-' from the string
    }
    for(let i = x.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if((Number(x[i]) && !reverse) || reverse){
            reverse += x[i];
        }
    }
    if(Number(s+reverse) > 2147483648 || (Number(s+reverse) < -2147483648 && Number(s+reverse) < 0)){
        return 0
    }
    return Number(s+reverse); // s='-' or ''
};
```