# Unsigned long in Java

Tags: java, long-integer, biginteger, unsigned

Currently, I am using signed values, -2^63 to 2^63-1. Now I need the same range (2 * 2^64), but with positive values only. I found the java documentations mentioning unsigned long, which suits this use.

I tried to declare 2^64 to a Long wrapper object, but it still loses the data, in other words, it only captures till the `Long.MAX_VALUE`, so I am clearly missing something. 
Is `BigInteger` the signed long that Java supports?

Is there a definition or pointer as to how to declare and use it?

Comment: BigInteger is the way to go.

Comment: Java only supports signed longs. Period. However, even an if there was such a thing as an unsigned long, 2^64 is too big to fit in it.

Comment: There is no unsigned long, but depending on the situation you may get away with *treating* a long as unsigned.

Comment: There is unsigned long

Comment: Possible this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508630/java-equivalent-of-unsigned-long-long

Answer (score 34):

In Java 8, unsigned `long` support was introduced. Still, these are typical longs, but the sign doesn't affect adding and subtracting. For dividing and comparing, you have dedicated methods in `Long`. Also, you can do the following:

```
long l1 = Long.parseUnsignedLong("12345678901234567890");
String l1Str = Long.toUnsignedString(l1)
```

`BigInteger` is a bit different. It can keep huge numbers. It stores them as `int[]` and supports arithmetic.

Answer (score 18):

Although Java has no unsigned long type, you can treat signed 64-bit two's-complement integers (i.e. `long` values) as unsigned if you are careful about it.

Many primitive integer operations are sign agnostic for two's-complement representations.   For example, you can use Java primitive addition, subtraction and multiplication on an unsigned number represented as a `long`, and get the "right" answer.

For other operations such as division and comparison, the `Long` class provides method like `divideUnsigned` and `compareUnsigned` that will give the correct results for unsigned numbers represented as `long` values.

The `Long` methods supporting unsigned operations were added in Java 8.  Prior to that, you could use 3rd-party libraries to achieve the same effect.  For example, the static methods in the Guava [`UnsignedLongs`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedLongs.html) class.

---

> Is `BigInteger` the signed long that Java supports?

`BigInteger` would be another way to represent integer values greater that `Long.MAX_VALUE`.  But `BigInteger` is a heavy-weight class.  It is unnecessary if your numbers all fall within the range 0 to 2<sup>64</sup> - 1 (inclusive).

Answer (score 4):

If using a third party library is an option, there is [jOOU](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOU) (a spin off library from [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org)), which offers wrapper types for unsigned integer numbers in Java. That's not exactly the same thing as having primitive type (and thus byte code) support for unsigned types, but perhaps it's still good enough for your use-case.

```
import static org.joou.Unsigned.*;

// and then...
UByte    b = ubyte(1);
UShort   s = ushort(1);
UInteger i = uint(1);
ULong    l = ulong(1);
```

All of these types extend `java.lang.Number` and can be converted into higher-order primitive types and `BigInteger`. In your case, earlier versions of jOOU simply stored the unsigned long value in a `BigInteger`. Version 0.9.3 does some cool bit shifting to fit the value in an ordinary `long`.

(Disclaimer: I work for the company behind these libraries)