# How to define Long Long data type in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    try {
        var sum: Long = 0
        val n: Int = readLine()!!.toInt()

        for (i in 0..(n - 1)) {
            var input: Long?
            input = readLine()!!.toLong()
            sum += input
        }
        println(sum)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        println(ex.message)
    } 
}
```

I want to take data Type Long Long replacing at Long . So how can I define Long Long data type?

Comment: As evident by the fundamentally differing answers, you should edit your question to include some context. What would this supposed `Long Long` do for you that `Long` doesn't?

Comment: Java itself has no `long long` type. `long` is 64-bit, `int` is 32-bit, `short` is 16-bit and `byte` is 8-bit. Kotlin doesn't change this.

Answer (score 9):

Kotlin's `Long` is 64-bit already. No need for ancient `long long` trickery:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html

Answer (score 2):

If you're on the JVM, there isn't a `long long` type, but you could use [`java.math.BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for arbitrarily large numbers instead.

See more discussion on this topic and some more alternatives at a Java question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/508630/4465208).

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin handles long long data type with the BigInteger data type. Replace the long with BigInteger;

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    try {
        var sum = 0.toBigInteger()
        val n: Int = readLine()!!.toInt()

        for (i in 0..(n - 1)) {
            var input: BigInteger?
            input = readLine()!!.toBigInteger()
            sum += input
        }
        println(sum)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        println(ex.message)
    } 
}
```