# Java - strange errors with unsigned values

Tags: java, junit, unsigned, short

There is 2-bytes array:
private byte[] mData;

and method:

```
public void setWord(final short pData) {
        mData[0] = (byte) (pData >>> 8);
        mData[1] = (byte) (pData);
}
```

I wrote the simple test:

```
public void testWord() {
        Word word = new Word();
        word.setWord((short) 0x3FFF);

        Assert.assertEquals(0x3F, word.getByte(0));
        Assert.assertEquals(0xFF, word.getByte(1));
}
```

The second assert fails with message "Expected 255, but was -1". 
I know, that 0xFF signed short is, in fact, -1, but why JUnit thinks, that they are not equal? And, what is the correct way to implement such classes?

Comment: Isn't the constant `0xff` an int? Which means that your second argument will be automatically cast to int.

Comment: I hate the lack of unsigned ints. This question is about that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430346/why-doesnt-java-support-unsigned-ints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not support unsigned types, so in order for a value to be 255, it must not be a signed byte, which is incapable of holding the value of 255. The 0xFF constant value will be taken as a signed int, and for the comparison, the byte value 0xFF will be converted to an int at -1 as well.

You need to type cast the literal 0xFF to be a byte. Change the assert to be `Assert.assertEquals((byte)0xFF, word.getByte(1));` Then the left hand side will evaluate to -1 as well as the right.

Answer (score 2):

The comment from `biziclop` is correct.
Any **Integer** number you specify in your code is considered an Integer unless marked otherwise.

Change your assertion to:

```
Assert.assertEquals((byte)0xFF, word.getByte(1))
```

And it should pass fine - as the first two bytes of the `integer` will be considered as a 
`byte`.

Bitwize speeking - basically when you write `0xFF` the compiler interprets it as `0x000000FF` which is `255`.
You want `0xFFFFFFFF` which is `-1`.

Casting to byte is the correct solution here

Comment: That's not completely true. 1.0 is a float and I think a number greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE is recognized as long.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I added the word 'Integer' after "Any".
As for numbers greater than MAX INT - unless specifically marked with `l` to specify they are `long` - it will not compile

Answer (score 1):

There are no unsigned types in java.

0xFF is the int 255 and casted to byte overflows to -1.

I usually work with bytes as integers if I want them unsigned. I usually do that this way:

```
int b1 = getByte() & 0xFF;
```

For example:

```
byte byte1 = 0xFF; // 255 = -1
byte byte2 = 0xFE; // 254 = -2
int int1 = (byte1 & 0xFF) + (byte1 & 0xFF); // 255 + 254 = 509
```