# how can i use unsigned in java

Tags: java, file-io

I need convert `integer` to `byte` and write byte in file but when i convert a number larger than 128 to byte in convert to a negative number.
I need to use unsigned char but i don't know how.
in c++ we write `unsigned` but how is it in java?

Comment: Java doesn't have `unsigned`.  Could you be more specific about what you're trying to do, and the results you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing bytes is not a problem, it doesn't matter whether you use `write(int)` or `writeByte(byte)` since the data written is still the same whether the byte is signed or unsigned. Reading bytes using `read()` also isn't a problem, because it returns unsigned bytes. Only when you're reading into a byte array do you need to be careful, because then you have to remember to mask each byte with `0xFF` when you use it.

Comment: This will generally work, unless you happen to be processing data which came from (or is going to) a system with different endian-ness

Answer (score 5):

Java doesn't have `unsigned` types by default but you can workaround it, see [Java and unsigned int, unsigned short, unsigned byte, unsigned long, etc. (Or rather, the lack thereof)](http://darksleep.com/player/JavaAndUnsignedTypes.html)

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't have unsigned types. I suggest you use a short, since it can accommodate all the values available to an unsigned char in languages like C and C++.

You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430346/why-doesnt-java-support-unsigned-ints) interesting.