# Convert unsigned long long to equivalent jni datatype?

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface

I'm working in Android jni and want to convert the unsigned long long C datatype to equivalent JNI wrapper. What should the equivalent jni wrapper be ? Also when I will write the JAVA function call which will call the jni wrapper, what should be the dataype of the JAVA method parameter for this unsigned long long datatype ?

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't know unsigned. All Java numerical primitives are signed ([blame Gosling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430346/why-doesnt-java-support-unsigned-ints)). If you will really need to transport the unsigned 64bit range over JNI (that is you need `[0,2^64]` not only `[-2^63,2^63-1]`) then there is no equivalent Java wrapper and you will need to decompose the value (like uppper four bytes and lower four bytes). Otherwise you can use simply Java primitive **long (JNI jlong)** as it is 64bit regardless of the processor architecture.

Comment: We are trying using byte[] for sending and receiving data. Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes you absolutely can use jbyteArray. However be careful about getting the endian-ness right. JVM is big endian but you cannot assume the endianness of the underlying hardware. Though it will be most probably a low endian, which is equally inconvenient. If in doubt, do an arithmetical decomposition (that is divide and modulo by 0xFF) instead of just calling out bytes by address.

Comment: If it answered your question, consider accepting and improve your rate.