# Signed and unsigned data types in java

Tags: java, types

I have a bit of confusion regarding which unsigned data types does Java support?

I have read [Why doesn't Java support unsigned ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430346/why-doesnt-java-support-unsigned-ints) but I don't understand its very complicated explanation (to me at least).

Comment: It keeps things simple.

Comment: Note: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15053268/829571

Comment: tldr: They were too confusing. Java doesn't have them.

Comment: Is there kind of unsigned float/double/short.Are they supported

Comment: Technically, `char` is an unsigned 2-byte integer, but don't use it as one. Other than that, everything is signed.

Comment: No, there is nothing unsigned in Java. (`char` is kind of but it is not numeric)

Comment: @zapl `char` is a numeric Java type. It supports all arithmetic operations.

Comment: @zapl try `char ch = '0'; ch *= 1.1; System.out.println(ch);` gives you `4`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik @PeterLawrey Aren't those operations carried out by casting to `int` (or whatever is appropriate) so that actual math is never done on `char`?

Comment: @zapl Quoting the [authoritative source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2): `The numeric types are the integral types and the floating-point types. The integral types are byte, short, int, and long, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, respectively, and char, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units.`

Comment: @zapl yes, the same as `byte` and `short`, but fundamentally it is a 16-bit value which is really a number.

Comment: `if ((char)-1 > (char)1) System.out.println("Ok, you win");`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Java only supports signed types (except `char`) because it was assumed that one type was simpler for beginners to understand than having two types for each size.  In C it was perceived to be a source of error so support for unsigned types was not included.

So the designers picked four sizes

- `byte`, 8 bit
- `short`, 16 bit
- `int`, 32 bit
- `long`, 64 bit.

and to keep things consistent they were all signed just like `float` and `double`  However a signed byte is rarely very useful and given they allowed unsigned 16-bit `char` having an unsigned `byte` might have made more sense.

Where this doesn't work so well is when you have to interact with systems which use unsigned integer types.  This can be source of confusion and to which type to use instead because often it doesn't make any difference.  Java 8 will have operations to support unsigned types as well.  These are added to the wrapper classes like `Integer` and `Long`

Answer (score 6):

All Java numeric types are signed. This was the designers decision. Some people think it was a bad idea to have signed byte. J.Bloch in an interview said "*I'm going to say that the strangest thing about the Java platform is that the byte type is signed*." http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=51624

Comment: `char` is unsigned. And byte should have been unsigned IMHO for the same reason. e.g. InputStream.read() reads an unsigned byte.

Comment: Joshua Bloch would say it is strange, but in C/C++ most implementations have a signed 8-bit `char`