# Convert 3 bytes array to number

Tags: java, arrays, byte, short

I convert a short number to a **3 byte array** using the following code:

```
static byte[] convertTo3ByteArray(short s) {

   byte[] ret = new byte[3];
   ret[0] = (byte) (s & 0xff);
   ret[1] = (byte) ((s >> 8) & 0xff);
   ret[2] = (byte) (0x00);

   return ret;
}
```

This works very well.

I found a code on Stackoverflow to convert the array back to a number:

```
static int convertToInt(byte[] b) {
   return ((b[0] << 0) | (b[1] << 8) | (b[2] << 16));
}
```

And when I convert **258** to byte array, and then use this code, it returns **258**.

But for number **675**, this code returns **-93**.

How do I have to change the **convertToShort** method to get **675** back?
I suppose it has something to do with bitshift and loss of data? Or signed bytes?

Comment: btw: You return a `int` instead of `short`.

Comment: Right! I have changed the method name so nobody gets confused. In the end it does not matter for me if it's an int or a short since I care about the number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this modified method:

```
static int convertToShort(byte[] b) {
    return (((b[0] & 0xFF) << 0) | ((b[1] & 0xFF) << 8) | ((b[2] & 0xFF) << 16));
}
```

In the array some bytes are negative, you need to convert them back to "positive values" with `byteVal & 0xFF` before doing the bit shift

Comment: Is there are difference between using "byteVal" and "byteVal & 0xFF"? Why , how ? Arent they same thing ?

Comment: @DavutÖzcan lets suppose that we have `short shortVal = 255; byte byteVal = shortVal;`, then the value of `byteVal` would be -1. If I do `byteVal & 0xFF` then the JVM do this: internally "converts" byteVal to int (of value -1) then it does the `&` bit op with 0xFF returning an integer value (255). In summary: not the same thing (byteVal = -1 and byteVal & 0xFF = 255)

Answer (score 1):

A short has 16 bits of information, so that would be two bytes. When you try to store a third byte with `| (b[2] << 16)`, it would go off the end of the short's bits, which is a problem. I.e. you can't do what you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Changing to using a `char` datatype will fix this issue as they are the only unsigned type in Java:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21089624/1590490

```
static char[] convertTo3ByteArray(short s) {

    char[] ret = new char[3];
    ret[0] = (char) (s & 0xff);
    ret[1] = (char) ((s >> 8) & 0xff);
    ret[2] = (char) (0x00);

    return ret;
}

static int convertToShort(char[] b) {
    return ((b[0]) | (b[1] << 8) | (b[2] << 16)); // the original << 0 shift does nothing
}
```