# Java: How many integers can a byte represent?

Tags: java

1 or 0 is one bit. A byte is 8 bits.

Why a byte can represent any integer from -128 to 127, inclusive, but not from 0 to 255?

Because 11,111,111 in binary is 255,  and you include 0, thats 256 integers you can represent in a byte.

Also, my book auhor just tells me it's 256 because 2 to 8th power. ok, it makes sense, but how? what's the math?

Comment: Do you understand how signed math works, especially two's complement?

Comment: what is signed math? like 2 and -2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Signed and unsigned data types in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089540/signed-and-unsigned-data-types-in-java)

Comment: There are 256 unique 8-bit values. A "byte" *can* represent an integer from 0 to 255, or a single ASCII character, or anything else that there are 256 of. The Java language designers chose to use integers -128 to 127 for the `byte` datatype.

Comment: 8 bits gives 256 different values ; the rest is a matter of convention.

Comment: byte can code up to 256 values (what they are depends on how you treat bit sequences). In your example byte can represent 256 sequential numbers either from -128 to 127 (256 in total including zero) or from 0 to 255 (256 including zero)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Java support unsigned ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430346/why-doesnt-java-support-unsigned-ints)

Comment: See also: "[James Gosling's explanation of why Java's byte is signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108297)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each bit can take two values, 0 and 1.

Since you have eight bits, and each can take values independent of the other bits, an 8-bit variable can take 2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2 = 2**8 = 256 distinct values.

It's up to the programmer to decide whether those values come from the [-128; 127] range, or from the [0; 255] range (both contain 256 different values). We call the former "signed 8-bit integers" and the latter "unsigned 8-bit integers".

Signed values are usually represented using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Java's [`byte`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) is an example of an 8-bit signed two's complement integer

> but why is it 2 to 8 power? thats the key question. Instead of adding 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1

Those numbers that you list are all powers of two: `128=2**7, 64=2**6, 32=2**5, ..., 1=2**0`. It is easy to show algebraically that when you add them up you get the next power of two minus one: `128+64+32+16+8+4+2+1=256-1`.

Comment: but why is it 2 to 8 power? thats the key question. Insteast of adding 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1

Comment: is that permutation?

Comment: @user132522: Also, `128+64+32+16+8+4+2+1` **is** `256-1` (easy to prove).

Comment: @user132522 As @NPE has just said, if you add up all powers of 2 you receive the next power of two minus 1: `sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} 2^i = 2^n - 1`

Answer (score 3):

Because byte stores signed values (both positive and negative). If you count from -128 to +127, it is 256 values. Java provides only signed byte values.

Also, it is 2^8 because a byte consist of 8 bits. Each bit can be either '0' or a '1', hence two possible values per bit (2^8).

```
1 bit -> 2^1 = 2 values 
2 bits -> 2^2 = 4 values
8 bits -> 2^8 = 256 values
n bits -> 2^n.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check ones' complement and two's complement to get better understanding via this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way: every additional digit doubles the number of possible outputs. If you have 1 digit, there are 2 possible outputs. 2 digits gives you 4 possible outputs. 3 digits gives you 8 possible outputs. So, there are `2^n` possible values for a binary number (where `n` is the number of digits).

Incidentally, this generalizes to other kinds of bases - the formula is `b^n` (where `b` is the base and `n` is the number of digits). So a 3-digit base-10 number has 10^3 possible values, for example. Obviously, binary is just base 2; other popular bases are 8 and 16, but there's no reason we have to limit it to that. We *could* do, for example, base 7 or base 9 or base 13 or something weird like that, but that's rarely done. (Base 8 is chosen because it's a multiple of 2 and evenly divides 24, which makes it convenient for 24-bit systems; base 16 is convenient for 32-bit and 64-bit machines for a similar reason - it's a lot more concise than binary but it's easier to convert between them).

As others have indicated, there *are*, in fact, 256 possible values of a byte - it's just that you have to choose whether you want that in the range of -128 to +127 or 0 to 255.