# Is Java char signed or unsigned for arithmetic?

Tags: java, char, unsigned

Java `char` is a 16 bit data type, but is it signed or unsigned when it comes to performing arithmetic on it?

Can you use it as an unsigned 16 bit integer in arithmetic?

For example, is the following correct?

```
char c1;
char c2;

int i = c1 << 16 | c2;
```

Or is it necessary to strip the sign-extended bits off c2 first?

(I am sure the answer to this is elsewhere, but there doesn't seem to be picked up by obvious searches).

Comment: Chars are unsigned but they are promoted to ints before bit shifting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21089624/3977134

Comment: @Michael I assume then that the promotion does not involve extension of the top bit (since there is no sign bit).

Comment: @r3dst0rm given that the second answer is essentially wrong in that question (which is pointed out in a comment), I think the issue needs clarifying (hence this question).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`char` is unsigned. From [JLS§4.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1):

> For char, from '\u0000' to '\uffff' inclusive, that is, from 0 to 65535

...but note that when you use any of the [various mathematic operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) on them (including bitwise operations and shift operations), they're widened to another type based on the type of the other operand, and that other type may well be signed:

> 2. Widening primitive conversion ([§5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - If either operand is of type `double`, the other is converted to `double`.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `float`, the other is converted to `float`.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `long`, the other is converted to `long`.
>    - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`.

For instance, `char + char` is `int`, so:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char a = 1;
        char b = 2;

        char c = a + b;          // error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Re bit-extension, if we follow [the link above](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) to widening primitive conversion:

> A widening conversion of a `char` to an integral type T zero-extends the representation of the char value to fill the wider format.

So `char` 0xFFFF becomes `int` 0x0000FFFF, not 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: Thanks: I feel the way the numeric range is specified (as unicode escapes) in the documenation doesn't leave it unambigously clear that this is how chars are treated arithmetically. They key question is how the widening happens. Is bit 15 propagated or not?

Comment: @rghome - Updated the end of the answer. No, it's 0-extended.

Answer (score 1):

From the [specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)

> For `char`, from `'\u0000'` to `'\uffff'` inclusive, that is, from 0 to 65535

Since it's 16 bits, it means they are unsigned.