# Extending the max value of an Integer by signing it in java

Tags: java

So I have tried doing this,

```
int extendedInteger = 0 & 0xff;
```

But that didn't seem to work,
I am trying to extend the max value by signing it,
So that it can hold more than Integer.MAX_VALUE.
I mean like making the Integer a 64 bit?

I'm still learning this language, And I'd appreciate any help given.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here - if you need to store values greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` then just use `long` instead of `int`.

Comment: I don't understand this at all. What is "signing it"?

Comment: Maybe "signing" is a term from other PL that he uses. Refer here for the sizes of primitive types in Java. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @harold I guess op tries to emulate [*unsigned* integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430346/why-doesnt-java-support-unsigned-ints), which are skewed to the right and lie between zero and 2^32 - 1.

Comment: @om-nom-nom so.. unsigning? That's easy enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Integer` (int) is a primitive type in java that takes up 32 bits in the memory. `int` *is* signed, and nothing you can do will change that.

What you want to do is use the primitive type `long`, which uses 64 bits in the memory, allowing it to store values up to `9223372036854775807`. `long` is also signed, meaning you can go to `-9223372036854775808`.

So your variable would be `long extendedInteger` instead.

Comment: I disagree with the later point, because the main reason to use signed integers (apart from business logic restrictions) is to save few bytes, which is not what long allows you to do.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Yeah but this isnt possible in java. Also, if OP is trying to make a memory-critical system, java probably isn't the language to go for

Comment: it is not entirely true because java 8 has limited support for unsigned arithmetic (comparisons, division, convertions)

Comment: Of course if you want to, you can let your negative integers act as unsigned if you do a lot of bit-tweeking in your code. But my point about java being a bad language for this kind of system becomes valid again.

Answer (score 2):

An int can have 2<sup>32</sup> different values, which ones they are is in principle up to you. It's just a matter of interpretation (though most possible interpretations are hard to do). If you want to interpret it as going from 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1, you can, and it's easy. That java "doesn't have unsigned integers" is not a serious problem, for most operations it doesn't make any difference:

- addition/subtraction
- bitwise and/or/xor
- left shift
- multiplication
- comparing for (in)equality

For some operations it does make a difference:

- right shift (use `>>>`)
- division (just cast to `long`)
- comparing (other) (cast to `long` or use `x <u y = (x ^ (1<<31)) <s (y ^ (1<<31))`)
- converting to string (cast to `long`)

Of course for those casts to `long`, you must undo the sign-extension, for example like
`value & 0xffffffffL`.

In Java 8, the `Integer` class contains functions that replace the above workarounds:

- `Integer.divideUnsigned`
- `Integer.compareUnsigned`
- `Integer.toUnsignedString`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean signed and unsigned like that in 'c++' java has no provision for that. For holding values greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE go for long.