# Why different byte array representation in Java and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, encoding, utf-8

I was trying to see the UTF-8 bytes of  in both Java and Javascript.

In Javascript,

`new TextEncoder().encode("");` returns => `[240, 159, 145, 141]`

while in Java,

`"".getBytes("UTF-8")` returns => `[-16, -97, -111, -115]`

I converted those byte arrays to hex string using methods I found corresponding to the language ([JS](https://jsperf.com/convert-byte-array-to-hex-string), [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855338/883832)) and both returned `F09F918D`

In fact, `-16 & 0xFF` gives => `240`

I am curious to know more on why both language chooses different ways of representing byte arrays. It took me a while to figure out up to this.

Comment: one is signed, one is unsigned. Still the same binary representation

Answer (score 4):

In Java all bytes are signed. Therefore, the range of one byte is from -128 to 127. In Javascript though, the returned values are, well, simply speaking integers. So it can be represented in decimal using the full range up to 255.

Therefore, if you convert both result to 1 byte hexadecimal representation - those would be the same: `F0 9F 91 8D`.

Speaking of *why* java decided to eliminate unsigned types, that is a separate [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430346/why-doesnt-java-support-unsigned-ints).