# What does bitwise-anding a byte with 0b1111_1111 do?

Tags: java, casting, bit-manipulation

I have the following method:

```
int convert3ByteChunkTo24Bits(final byte[] bytes) {
    int bitsFor3ByteChunk = 0;

    bitsFor3ByteChunk = bitsFor3ByteChunk | (bytes[0] & 0b11111111);

    bitsFor3ByteChunk = bitsFor3ByteChunk << 8;
    bitsFor3ByteChunk = bitsFor3ByteChunk | (bytes[1] & 0b11111111);

    bitsFor3ByteChunk = bitsFor3ByteChunk << 8;
    bitsFor3ByteChunk = bitsFor3ByteChunk | (bytes[2] & 0b11111111);

    return bitsFor3ByteChunk & 0b00000000_11111111_11111111_11111111;
}
```

Purpose of the method is to append bytes passed and return it in an int format. Here is a test method I have:

```
void testConvert3ByteChunkTo24Bits() {
    final byte ca = (byte) 0xCA;
    final byte fe = (byte) 0xFE;
    final byte ba = (byte) 0xBA;

    final byte[] man = {ca, fe, ba};
    final int bytesIn24Bits = base64EncoderHelper.convert3ByteChunkTo24Bits(man);

    System.out.println(bytesIn24Bits);
}
```

Output of the result will be:

```
13303482
```

which in binary is:

```
00000000110010101111111010111010
```

This is correct and is the intended results since:

```
0xCA = 11001010
0xFE = 11111110
0xBA = 10111010
```

So, so far so good. There is just one thing I do not understand, why do I need the logical ands as in

```
(bytes[0] & 0b11111111)
```

When I do not do the bitwise-and operations, so if the implementation is as follows:

```
int convert3ByteChunkTo24Bits(final byte[] bytes) {
    int bitsFor3ByteChunk = 0;

    bitsFor3ByteChunk = bitsFor3ByteChunk | (bytes[0]);

    bitsFor3ByteChunk = bitsFor3ByteChunk << 8;
    bitsFor3ByteChunk = bitsFor3ByteChunk | (bytes[1]);

    bitsFor3ByteChunk = bitsFor3ByteChunk << 8;
    bitsFor3ByteChunk = bitsFor3ByteChunk | (bytes[2]);

    return bitsFor3ByteChunk & 0b00000000_11111111_11111111_11111111;
}
```

result will be:

```
00000000111111111111111110111010
```

What am I missing? What does

```
bytes[0] & 0b11111111
```

fix here? (I found it kind of by trial - error and still curious why it works..)

Comment: Sign extension? Take a byte of value 0xFF, store it into an int and observe what you get.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès sign extension but at what point?

Comment: Byte variables are converted to int in expressions, so are sign extended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```
bitsFor3ByteChunk = bitsFor3ByteChunk | (bytes[0] & 0b11111111);
```

`bytes[0]` is first extended to `int` value (integers are all represented in two's-complement). Then for a value like `0xFF` stored in a `byte`, the corresponding `int` value will be `0xFFFFFFFF`. It is then masked to retain the lower 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

It handles signed bytes.

say `byte[0]` has a value of 0b10000000. That's looks like 128 to you and me, but to Java it looks like `-128`, due to [two's complement arithmatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). When you use that value in a calculation with an int, it'll be sign-extended to an int with a value of `11111111111111111111111110000000`, which is an int with a value of `-128`

To avoid the problem, this code performs a bitwise and with `0b11111111`. This is an integer operation, so the byte is implicitly cast to the int `11111111111111111111111110000000`, but the `and` turns it into `00000000000000000000000010000000`, which is the desired 128.

This is a hack for the notorious Java problem of [not having unsigned types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430346/why-doesnt-java-support-unsigned-ints).

Answer (score 0):

The human-readable equivalent is simply

```
Byte.toUnsignedInt(b)
```

or if you want it really explicitly but inefficiently:

```
b < 0?  b + 256: b
```

Honestly, writing code like that when jdk methods or simple math exist to do the same thing is just obfuscation and I hope people who write code like that don't ever end up in a team with other people... Unless they're writing a device driver in C or some other inherently low-level byte-wrangling project like that.