# Java: Why doesn't binary OR work as expected (see code below)?

Tags: java, binary

I don't understand the output from the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i1, i2, i3, i4;
    byte b;
    i1 = 128;
    b = (byte) i1;
    i2 = (int) b;
    i3 = 0 | b;
    i4 = 1 << 7;
    System.out.format("i1: %d   b: %d   i2: %d   i3: %d   i4: %d\n", i1, b, i2, i3, i4);
}
```

Output:

```
i1: 128   b: -128   i2: -128   i3: -128   i4: 128
```

Because `byte` is an 8-bit [two's-complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twos_complement) signed integer, the binary representations with a 1 in the most significant bit are interpreted as negative values, which is why `b` becomes `-128`, which I'm totally fine with. I also understand that it's probably a good idea to keep the interpretation consistent when casting, as with `i2`. But shouldn't `i3` and `i4` have identical bit patterns and therefore map to identical `int` values?

Comment: i would just like to express my indignation about Java's bytes. As I learned it, byte is by definition a number between 0 and 255 and therefore the complete mess they have done to byte in Java can not be excused. The -128..127 calls for a new primitive data type.

Comment: I would like to see that definition.  The definitions I googled say that a byte is 8 bits, enough to represent a character.

Comment: I guess I just got so used to the idea that the color components R G B are BYTES in range 0..255. Also the ASCII table maps characters to numbers in this range. I have never tried typing Alt+(-)+(number), it's always been a positive number 0..255. I was appalled by the conception of byte data type in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sign extension is what is making `i2` and `i3` negative.

In the expression `(0 | b)`, `b` is promoted to an int, and sign extension occurs as part of this promotion.

That's not happening in the  expression assigned to `i4`. The constants `1` and `7` are already ints so there's no sign extension involved.

Comment: I would have said that 1 and 7 are int type and so is the result so that why is no sign extension involved.

Comment: Yeah - that's both more correct and easier to understand than what I wrote - edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 5):

In this line:

```
i3 = 0 | b;
```

The "b" variable is automatically promoted to `int` type with sign extension because of the `|` operator, so becomes `(int)-128`, i.e. `0xffffff80`.

When "or"ed with zero, its still the same value, namely -128

Answer (score 4):

No, `i4` is not a byte value, it's an `int`. That means that its sign bit is bit 31, not bit 7.

**UPDATE**: `i3` is an `int` too, but it is initialized by extending a `byte`, so it keeps the sign from the `byte` value.

Comment: But i3 is also an int... why is it negative then?

Comment: The i3 assignment is similar to the i2 assignment... The expression returns a byte that is cast to an int.

Answer (score 2):

`i2 = (int) b;`

`i3 = 0 | b;`

the i3 statement is equivalent to:

`i3 = 0 | ((int) b) = 0 | i2` so naturally it is going to have the same value as i2

Answer (score 1):

In

```
i3 = 0 | b;
```

I'm guessing the 0 | b part is evaluated as a byte, and the results are then cast to an int, while in

```
i4 = 1 << 7;
```

the 1 << 7 part is already an int.

**The above guess has been pointed out in the comments to be wrong!**

The correct version is: In the top expression, the b is already cast to an int with sign extension before the OR operation.

Comment: “0 | b” is _not_ evaluated as a byte. “b” is widened to int before the OR operation.

Answer (score 1):

That's simple. `i3 = 0 | b;` gets evaluated like `byte`, then it is converted to `int`. Whereas `i4 = 1 << 7;` will evaluate value as `int` and assign it to `int`. So in the first case we get `10000000b` cast to `int` from `byte`, which will give us `-128`. And in the second we just assign this value to `int` without cast, which gives us `128`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the unsigned value of the bit pattern in a byte:

```
b & 0xff
```

See also [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397867/port-of-random-generator-from-c-to-java/397997#397997).

Comment: Do you happen to know the exact reason why & works and | doesn't?