# Integer.parseInt large number and retain sign?

Tags: java, parseint

I'm working with hex values and I need to retain the sign of the values. I'm wondering if someone has a creative way to retain the sign of the int without using `BigInteger`? I can't use `BigInteger` because it's not in my library due to size limitations; my program runs in an embedded environment.

I have a string of hex values as follows:
`55844d000000000080027d801cf6380006f416c0c23d3e4000000000`

```
    String          ssumI = null;
    String          ssumQ = null;
    String          sazI   = null;
    float           isumI = 0;
    float           isumQ = 0;
    float           iazI  = 0;

    ssumI = data.substring(0,8); 
    isumI = (float)(Integer.parseInt(ssumI, 16)/Math.pow(2,bits));
    //55844d00 parses fine

    ssumQ = data.substring(8,16); 
    isumQ = (float)(Integer.parseInt(ssumQ, 16)/Math.pow(2,bits));
    //00000000 parses fine

    sazI = data.substring(16, 24); 
    iazI = (float)(Integer.parseInt(sazI, 16)/Math.pow(2,bits));
    //80027d80 fails - NumberFormatException
    //should be -1,036,173,760 and in the int range
```

Am I not understanding the failure correctly? It seems like the failure is due to the sign bit being set.

Comment: BigInteger is the obvious solution here - so why don't you use it?

Comment: It's not in my library due to size limitations, my program runs in an embedded environment

Comment: Right, so you should put that in your question. Any time the obvious solution is inappropriate because you're in an unusual context, you should explain that context.

Comment: unless bits is a floating-point value or larger than 31, use `1 << bits` instead of `Math.pow(2,bits)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store 32 bits at a time, the obvious solution in my view would be to parse with `Long.parseLong` instead:

```
isumI = (float)(Long.parseLong(ssumI, 16) / Math.pow(2, bits));
```

(Do you definitely want to hold these values as `float` though? You're losing information that way...)

Answer (score 0):

If [Java 8](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/unsigned_api) is available you can use the new unsigned operations in it ([How to use the unsigned integer in java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25556017/995714)).

```
isumI = (float)(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(ssumI, 16)/Math.pow(2,bits));
```

But since each string has 32 bits, I suppose `bits` is less than 32. In that case you can rewrite it as

```
isumI = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(ssumI, 16)/(float)(1 << bits);
```

If `bits` can be larger than 32 (but less than 64), replace `1` by `1L`

Also, notice that bits is unchanged in your function, you should replace `Math.pow(2, bits)` with `1 << bits` and store it in a separate variable instead of recalculating it again and again.

Anyway if you intend to use the string as a big value then you should store it in an `int` array. A `float` has only 24 bits of significand and you may lose the low 8 bits if the value is large.