# Java Bits Shift on Unsigned Integer

Tags: java, int, bit-shift, unsigned

I understand that java has no unsigned int, however as of Java SE 8, there are methods to use integer datatype to perform unsigned arithmetic. How do I go about doing bits shift to "unsigned int" in java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the unsigned integer in java 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556017/how-to-use-the-unsigned-integer-in-java-8)

Comment: to shift unsigned, use `>>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do all bitwise operations the same way you do them for signed `int`, using `>>>` to shift right. "Unsigned" features serve just for outputting and converting, they don't affect inner bit representation.

For example:

```
int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 1024 - 1023;
System.out.println(Integer.toUnsignedString(i) + "=" + Integer.toBinaryString(i));
i = i >>> 10;
System.out.println(Integer.toUnsignedString(i) + "=" + Integer.toBinaryString(i));
i = i << 21;
System.out.println(Integer.toUnsignedString(i) + "=" + Integer.toBinaryString(i));
```

resulting output:

```
2096128=111111111110000000000                // 11 ones, 10 zeros
2047=11111111111                             // 11 ones, 0 zeros
4292870144=11111111111000000000000000000000  // 11 ones, 21 zeros
```