# Bit calculation on long argument overflows as if it were int

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Could someone explain me why the following computation overflows?

```
938372878L | (1 << 31) //results to -1209110770
```

It behaves as if the number were integer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556017/how-to-use-the-unsigned-integer-in-java-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1` is an `int` literal, which is why `(1 << 31)` overflows. You should change it to `1L` for it to be treated as `long` :

```
938372878L | (1L << 31)
```

This results in

```
3085856526
```

Comment: @RichardChambers What do you mean? Java doesn't have unsigned long.