# byte array to unsigned int in java

Tags: java

I'm converting a byte array into `int` by doing this:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream (data);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream (bais);
int j = dis.readInt();
```

But it returns a signed number where I want an unsigned number, because I want to send that number to the server as an integer during encryption and have to decrypt it at server. if it is a signed number i can do that.

please any 1 help me..........

venu

Comment: In Java all integer types (except char) are signed.

Comment: What protocol do you use? If you send something to the server the "something" and how it is sent is important, not your internal representation. I think, your question should sound like: "How do i send unsigned numbers using corba/RMI/Hessian/t3/iiop/http/.....?"

Answer (score 12):

An `int` is always a signed, 32-bit number in Java. However, this only matters if you are doing math with it. If all you care about is the pattern of 0 and 1 bits, simply ignore the sign.

If you do need to do some math, convert it to a `long` by masking:

```
long l = j & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
```

Do all arithmetic with `long` operands, modulo 0xFFFFFFFFL. When you are done, cast the result back to an `int` and transmit it.

Comment: Brilliant! very accurate and helpful!

Answer (score 7):

Java's primitive integer types (i.e. byte, short, int and long) are all signed.  But you can work around this.

To do (say) 32 bit unsigned arithmetic, just do the arithmetic pretending that 'int' is unsigned.  For example, `2**31 - 1` is the largest (signed) `int` value.  If you add one to it you will get `-2**31`.  But that bit pattern is the same as `+2**31` if you think of the `int` as being unsigned.  This also works for subtraction and multiplication.  (I'm not sure about division and remainder, but the chances are that doesn't matter for you).

Comparing unsigned 32 bit values is a bit more tricky.  For example, `-1` is less that `+1`, but if you interpret `-1` as an unsigned value you get `+2**32 - 1` which should be greater than '+1'.  You can compensate by translating the inequality (I'll leave it to the reader to figure it out) or by casting the `int` values to `long`, masking them with `0xffffffffL` and comparing them as longs; e.g.

```
int u1 = ...
int u2 = ...
if ((((long) u1) & 0xffffffff) < (((long) u2) & 0xffffffff) {
    // u1 represents a smaller unsigned value than u2
}
```

Converting 32 bit unsigned integers to Strings is easiest done using longs; e.g.

```
String str = Long.toString(((long) u1) & 0xffffffffL);
```

Now I'll freely admit that using `int` to represent 32 bit unsigned values is tricky, and potentially error prone.  A cleaner solution would be to use `long` throughout, or if your application needs 64 bit unsigned values to use `BigInteger`.

---

**UPDATE** - it looks Java 8 will have support (in the form of library methods) for treating `int` and `long` as unsigned types - see ["Unsigned Integer Arithmetic API now in JDK 8"](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/unsigned_api) by Joseph Darcy @ Oracle.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397867/port-of-random-generator-from-c-to-java/397997#397997

Answer (score 0):

Each cell in the array is treated as unsigned int:

```
private int unsignedIntFromByteArray(byte[] bytes) {
    int res = 0;
    if (bytes == null)
        return res;

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        res = (res *10) + ((bytes[i] & 0xff));
    }
    return res;
}
```

- The code will convert [12,34] to 1234

Answer (score -4):

Java does not have unsigned int, so you'll have to manually invert the bits to get an unsigned value if you absolutely need to have one.

[Got this from Google](http://www.javaworld.com/javaforums/showflat.php?Cat=&Board=javabeginner&Number=1019&page=7&view=collapsed&sb=6&o=&fpart=1).