# How do I split an integer into 2 byte binary?

Tags: java

Given

```
private int width = 400;
private byte [] data = new byte [2];
```

I want to split the integer "width" into two bytes and load data[0] with the high byte and data[1] with the low byte.

That is binary value of 400 = 1 1001 0000 
so data[0] should contain 0000 0001
and data[1] should contain 1001 0000

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Using simple bitwise operations:

```
data[0] = (byte) (width & 0xFF);
data[1] = (byte) ((width >> 8) & 0xFF);
```

**How it works:**

- `& 0xFF` masks all but the lowest eight bits.
- `>> 8` discards the lowest 8 bits by moving all bits 8 places to the right.
- The cast to byte is necessary because these bitwise operations work on an `int` and return an `int`, which is a bigger data type than `byte`. The case is safe, since all non-zero bits will fit in the `byte`. For more information, see [*Conversions and Promotions*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html).

**Edit:** [Taylor L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105744/taylor-l) correctly remarks that though `>>` works in this case, it may yield incorrect results if you generalize this code to *four* bytes (since in Java an `int` is 32 bits). In that case, it's better to use `>>>` instead of `>>`. For more information, see the [Java tutorial on *Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Comment: >> might not be what you want. >>> doesn't carry the sign bit when you shift so that is probably better to use in this case if you want to capture all 4 bytes.

Comment: if I do "new byte[]{width & 0xFF, (width >> 8) & 0xFF}" the compiler says "possible loss of precision required byte found int"

Comment: @Kevin: I see I forgot to cast to `byte`. Will update the answer.

Comment: @Taylor: Will check it out, but why is Stephan's code not working?

Comment: @Kevin: I added an explanation for that fact as well.

Comment: @Stephan: Thanks, its doing fine now

Comment: You don't need the mask, the cast will cut off the excess bits. It doesn't matter whether you use >> or >>>, the ones due to sign extension will be cut off. Though I'd consider >>> better style.

Answer (score 13):

For converting two bytes the cleanest solution is

```
data[0] = (byte) width;
data[1] = (byte) (width >>> 8);
```

For converting an integer to four bytes the code would be

```
data[0] = (byte) width;
data[1] = (byte) (width >>> 8);
data[2] = (byte) (width >>> 16);
data[3] = (byte) (width >>> 24);
```

It doesn't matter whether >> or >>> is used for shifting, any one bits created by sign extension will not end up in the resulting bytes.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397867/port-of-random-generator-from-c-to-java/397997#397997).

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you want for a 4 byte int. Note, it stores the low byte at offset 0. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to order them as needed.

```
public static byte[] intToBytes(int x) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];

    for (int i = 0; x != 0; i++, x >>>= 8) {
        bytes[i] = (byte) (x & 0xFF);
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Integer is 32 bits (=4 bytes) in java, you know?

width & 0xff will give you the first byte, 
width & 0xff00 >> 8 will give you the second, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To get the high byte, shift right by 8 bits then mask off the top bytes. Similarly, to get the low byte just mask off the top bytes.

```
data[0] = (width >> 8) & 0xff;
data[1] = width & 0xff;
```

Comment: Apologies - was trying to illustrate the principle, but you're quite right!

Answer (score 0):

```
int width = 400;
byte [] data = new byte [2];

data[0] = (byte) ((width & 0xFF00) >> 8);
data[1] = (byte) (width & 0xFF);

for(int b = 0; b < 2; b++) {
    System.out.println("printing byte " + b);
    for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(data[b] & 1);
        data[b] = (byte) (data[b] >> 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at the source for HeapByteBuffer.  It has the conversion code for all primitive data types. (In fact you could just use a ByteBuffer ;)