# Audio signal plotting code explanation

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand every single line of the following code , but my knowledge prevents me from
being successful.

It's actually a piece of code taken form a java tutorial regarding the plotting of an audio signal (waveform)

In a nutshell what the code does is basically:
if audio data sample size is equal to 16 and encoding type is BigEndian do this...
Well.. the problem is that I'd like to be able to catch the meaning of every single code statement..
Can anyone help me ?
Many thanks in advance...
The original code is here: 
http://www.koders.com/java/fid3508156A13C80A263E7CE65C4C9D6F5D8651AF5D.aspx?s=%22David+Anderson%22
(class SamplingGraph )

The code I'd like to understand is the following:

```
if (format.getSampleSizeInBits() == 16) {
    int nlengthInSamples = audioBytes.size() / 2;
    audioData = new int[nlengthInSamples];

    if (format.isBigEndian()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nlengthInSamples; i++) {
        /* First byte is MSB (high order) */
        int MSB = (int) audioBytes.get(2 * i);
        /* Second byte is LSB (low order) */
        int LSB = (int) audioBytes.get(2 * i + 1);
        audioData[i] = MSB << 8 | (255 & LSB);
        }
```

Especially how would you translate in words the following code:

```
audioData[i] = MSB << 8 | (255 & LSB);
```

...thanks again
Mat

Answer (score 2):

That's what is called a [bitwise operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations); it manipulates the numbers at the bit level.

- `<<` is the bitwise left shift operator ([JLS 15.19 Shift Operators](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.19))
- `|` and `&` are bitwise "or" and "and" respectively ([JLS 15.22.1 Integer Bitwise Operators &, ^, and |](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.22.1))

The snippet combines 2 `byte` for 16-bit samples into an `int` in [big endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) format.

255, which in binary is `11111111` (i.e, a sequence of 8 ones), is used to "mask" the lower `byte`, to undo any [sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) (`byte` in Java is a signed numeric type). It's typical to use the hexadecimal representation `0xFF` instead of the decimal 255 in these kinds of operations.

---

If you don't want to get down and dirty with bit level manipulation, there should be libraries that can do this for you in a robust way.

#### Related questions

- [How do I split an integer into 2 byte binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735840/how-do-i-split-an-integer-into-2-byte-binary)

  - This is the reverse operation, `int` to `byte[]`
- [Convert 4 bytes to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383265/convert-4-bytes-to-int)
- [James Gosling’s explanation of why Java’s byte is signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108297/james-goslings-explanation-of-why-javas-byte-is-signed)

Comment: The linked "Convert 4 bytes to int" is very informative; it also mentions `ByteBuffer` which provides these kinds of functionalities for you.

Answer (score 2):

MSB = Most significant bits (the first half)
LSB = Least significant bits (the second half)

This code snippet is confirming that the sample size is 16 bits and in [big-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Big-endian) format. Then it is calculating the MSB and LSB for the sample. Finally, it is combining the MSB and LSB by shifting the MSB to the left 8 bits and then adding in the LSB with a mask that ensures only the lower 8 bits of the LSB are used.

Answer (score 0):

```
audioData[i] = MSB << 8 | (255 & LSB);
```

**MSB** - Most Significant Bit

**LSB** - Least Significant Bit

```
MSB << 8     // shift the MSB to the left by 8 bitposition
Example: 00000000 00000010 -> 00000010 00000000

(255 & LSB)  // masking the LSB, so that we have LSB if it is less then 255 or 0
Example: 00000000 00000010 -> 00000000 00000010
         00000010 00000000 -> 00000000 00000000

// The OR operation '|' is putting both together
Example: 00000010 00000000 | 00000000 00000010 -> 00000010 00000010
```