# Casting int to char in java- must I use ASCII?

Tags: java, char, casting, character

Q: When casting an int to a char in Java, it seems that the default result is the ASCII character corresponding to that int value.  My question is, is there some way to specify a different character set to be used when casting?

(Background info: I'm working on a project in which I read in a string of binary characters, convert it into chunks, and convert the chunks into their values in decimal, ints, which I then cast as chars.  I then need to be able to "expand" the resulting compressed characters back to binary by reversing the process.
I have been able to do this, but currently I have only been able to compress up to 6 "bits" into a single character, because when I allow for larger amounts, there are some values in the range which do not seem to be handled well by ASCII; they become boxes or question marks and when they are cast back into an int, their original value has not been preserved.  If I could use another character set, I imagine I could avoid this problem and compress the binary by 8 bits at a time, which is my goal.)

I hope this was clear, and thanks in advance!

Comment: "A string of binary characters", huh?

Comment: Are the ints >0 and <128 or even <255?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem has nothing to do with ASCII or character sets.

In Java, a `char` is just a 16-bit integer. When casting ints (which are 32-bit integers) to chars, the only thing you are doing is keeping the 16 least significant bits of the int, and discarding the upper 16 bits. This is called a *narrowing conversion*.

References:

- http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html#20232
- http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html#25363

Answer (score 1):

The conversion between characters and integers uses the [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) values, of which ASCII is a subset. If you are handling binary data you should avoid characters and strings and instead use an integer array - note that Java doesn't have unsigned 8-bit integers.

Comment: He mentions he's *casting* from int to char. This has nothing to do with character sets: Chars are nothing but 16-bit integers; casting just keeps the lower 16 bits and discards the upper 16 bits.

Comment: @Grodriguez: A `char` is a 16-bit integer *with an associated meaning as text*. The fact that it is 16-bit is more a historic coincidence - it could just as easily have been 24 bits. If you just want a 16-bit integer you should use a `short`. Using a `char` to store arbitrary binary data is not a good approach - that's not what `char` was designed for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841461/unsigned-short-in-java/1841471#1841471

Comment: Regardless of the "intended use", the fact is that a char *is* a 16-bit unsigned integer. While I agree that using a char to store binary data is not a good approach, saying that "the conversion between characters and integers uses Unicode values" is misleading. Casting from int to char results in a narrowing primitive conversion as defined by the JLS (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html#25363).

Answer (score 0):

What you search for in not a cast, it's a conversion.

There is a String constructor that takes an array of byte and a charset encoding. This should help you.

Comment: Thank you, I did find out about this method.  I just wondered if there was a way to change how casting worked, as this would mean I could improve my existing implementation with just a simple modification.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working on a project in which I
>   read in a string of binary characters,
>   convert it into chunks, and convert
>   the chunks into their values in
>   decimal, ints, which I then cast as
>   chars. I then need to be able to
>   "expand" the resulting compressed
>   characters back to binary by reversing
>   the process.

You don't mention *why* you are doing that, and (to be honest) it's a little hard to follow what you're trying to describe (for one thing, I don't see why the resulting characters would be "compressed" in any way.

If you just want to represent binary data as text, there are plenty of [standard ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) of accomplishing that. But it sounds like you may be after something else?

Comment: Sorry about that, I just didn't want to make a wall of text that nobody would be interested in reading.

Comment: Errr, didn't realize hitting Enter would post, let me elaborate: the project involves Huffman encoding; we were required to convert text from a .txt file, into binary, and be able to decode that binary to get the original text. A bonus was offered if we could store the encoded text in a compressed form, and I decided to simply grab the binary in chunks and instead of printing zeroes and ones, I take the decimal value of the binary chunk and cast that as a char, giving me one character for many.  That's all I mean by compression.

Comment: And yes, I found out there were other ways of achieving this, but at this point I have already finished the project, but because certain values don't produce a character, when casted as a char, that retains the value, I only have it working by taking 6 binary characters at a time. I was only wondering if there was a way to force casting to use some other character set, so I could try to find one that worked for, say, chunks of 8.

Comment: Ah, OK, so the file is a text file with '1' and '0' characters, not a binary file?

Why not just store it as an actual binary file? Convert each set of 8 bit characters to a byte value and store it as a byte (using FileOutputStream, for example).

As mentioned before, when casting to char, you are not casting to a character set, just to an integer value (which is converted to a specific character encoding when you print it), so if you happen on character which are not printable in Unicode, randomly choosing a different character set is unlikely to help.

Comment: If you do need to store the data as text, Base64 encoding is a common way to make sure you're only using printable characters.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info, this answers my question.  I guess the only way to achieve better compression would be to use one of the other solutions such as the one you've suggested.  Fair enough, and thanks again!