# Java Set of Bytes

Tags: java

Can anyone help me to know how can I have a "Set" of Bytes in Java?
Thank you

Answer (score 10):

#### `Set<Byte>` option from the Java Collections Framework

If you want to harness the Java Collections Framework, you can have a [`java.util.Set<Byte>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). Unfortunately Java generics doesn't work with primitive. [`java.lang.Byte`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html) is the box type for `byte`. Perhaps an implementation that you can use is a [`TreeSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html); it is a [`SortedSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html), so you can sort the (boxed) `byte` by their natural ordering.

#### See also

- [Java Language Guide/Autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)
- [Java Tutorials/Collections Framework](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)

#### Related questions

- [Generics over objects only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015716/java-noob-generics-over-objects-only) (yes, unfortunately)

---

#### `BitSet` option for performance

Another option is a [`java.util.BitSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html). This is a very time and space efficient data structure that implements set representation using bits, i.e. an `int i` is "in the set" if bit `i` is set.

`BitSet` is not part of the Java Collections Framework.

Here's an example usage:

```
    BitSet bytes = new BitSet();

    bytes.set(3);
    bytes.set(7);
    bytes.set(11);
    bytes.set(11);
    bytes.set(1000);

    System.out.println(bytes);
    // {3, 7, 11, 1000}

    System.out.println(bytes.cardinality()); // 4

    System.out.println(bytes.get(10)); // false
```

Note that you may `set` bits that are out of the `byte` range.

In fact, you can't directly `set` all bits in the `byte` range, since `byte` is a signed datatype in Java. You can use bit masking to convert any `byte` to an `int` in the `0..255` range as follows:

```
    byte b = -1;
    // bytes.set(b); // throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
    bytes.set(b & 0xFF);
    System.out.println(bytes);
    // {3, 7, 11, 255, 1000}
```

You can then iterate over all `byte` in the set as follows:

```
    for (int i = -1; (i = bytes.nextSetBit(i + 1)) != -1; ) {
        byte b = (byte) i;
        System.out.println(b);
    }
    // 3, 7, 11, -1, -24
```

Note that because of the `byte [-128,127]` to `int [0,255]` mapping, negatives come after positives. `BitSet` also facilitates efficient set operations against other `BitSet`, like `or`, `and`, `xor`, `equals`, `intersects`, etc.

#### Related questions

- [James Gosling’s explanation of why Java’s `byte` is signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108297/james-goslings-explanation-of-why-javas-byte-is-signed)

  - The range of Java's `byte` is `-128..127`, not `0..255`.

Comment: You must have a lot of time on your hands... good in depth answer though

Answer (score 4):

As polygenelubricants says, you can have a `Set<Byte>`. Another simple alternative would be to have:

```
boolean[] byteSet = new boolean[256];
```

This would be very efficient to check or set each value - and iterating over the set of values would only take 256 iterations anyway :)

Comment: If the set is to be modified frequently, I think I would go with this solution (or a simple class that wrapped it). Constant autoboxing could slow it down.

Comment: How does this cope with bytes having negative values?

Comment: @Tom: You'd just add 128 to any index or something similar. Various ways of coping with it. Fundamentally we just need 256 boolean values though.

Comment: @Nick: Note that in this case autoboxing probably wouldn't be **too** bad as all the boxed byte values are cached - it wouldn't be creating objects constantly.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a `Set<Byte>` but not a `Set<byte>`, Byte being an object and byte a primitive. If you create a set of Byte then you can add byte values to it and they will be auto-boxed to Bytes on the fly, giving you the expected result.

```
    Set<Byte> byteSet = new HashSet<Byte>();
    byte b1 = 1;
    Byte b2 = 1;
    byte b3 = 2;
    byteSet.add(b1);
    byteSet.add(b2);
    byteSet.add(b3);
    System.out.println(byteSet);
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 2]
```

It should be noted that, although this method is quite clear and uses the familiar Java Collections Framework, the auto-boxing can become a performance issue if you are doing lots of work on the set -- but to see this effect you are really going to have to hammer it.

More performant alternatives have been suggested, like `java.util.BitSet` by polygenelubricants, or Jon Skeet's array solution.

Comment: thanks for all answers. I dont need to manipulate the Set. All I need is to have a pair of IP addresses (source and destination). Then per each pair i need to keep two pieces of information. May be two sets which will be mapped based on their index! like setA:  set of IP addresses, Set B information about those ip addresses.

Comment: @Red Lion: Then you want a `Map<IPAddress,IPInfo>` instead of two sets. Look at the link in my answer about what `Map` interface provides.

Comment: @Polygenlubricants: i cant use map as it maps one key to only one value. wat i need is saving
192.168.1.65
209.85.229.91
140045
0.00124

4 pieces of information all together.

Answer (score 1):

If you often need collections containing primitive types, have a look at the [Primitive Collections for Java](http://pcj.sourceforge.net/). It implements the main types of collections for each primitive type, which should be faster and more memory efficient than using the wrapper Byte class.

Other similar libraries are available.