# Why are bytes signed in Java?

Tags: java

I would like to know more about bytes that are signed in Java
What make then signed. I tried to Google I don't get clarity, but if some can clearly explain to me maybe I will get it.
Why are bytes signed in Java?

Comment: This is about as authoritative as it will get: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3108328/3419894

Comment: Almost everything is signed in Java. You cant choose between signed and unsigned in Java, therefore for purpose of working with negative numbers, you need having unsigned variables.

Comment: OK that's more understandable when you talking about working with negative values or numbers.