# Signed bytes in Java, What's the big idea?

Tags: java

Byte value is between 0 and 255, very simple and straight forward. Java didn't think so however and decided that values to be between -128 and 128 and ruined my life and many others.

I just want to know what's the big idea? why everytime i need to get the unsigned byte value do I have to do this:

```
int byteValue = (int) javaByte & 0xFF;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3108328/3459206

Comment: Because you're doing a bitwise operation on ints with that conversion. It really looks like this `((int) javaByte) & 0x000000FF;`

Comment: Josh Bloch has said that he thinks the decision to make `byte` signed is the strangest thing about Java.

Comment: "Byte value is between 0 and 255"  No, a byte is 8 bits.  What you do with those bits is a different issue.

Comment: by the way, they are from -128 to **127**.

Answer (score 1):

Java supports only signed integers. `byte` is integer number as well so Java is just consistent here.

This is not case for C for example where `char` type doesn't have defined whether it's `signed` or `unsigned`. You need to explicitly tell. This is in my opinion much worse than saying that it's by default `signed`.

Anyway, the original intention in C for char was a string character where the unsigned made sense. In Java there is different type for string character - `char`.

Comment: In Pascal, which predated C, values of type Byte were stored as unsigned, but arithmetic on them was performed as signed as a result of promotion to Integer.  Many C implementations behaved likewise except when "char" and "int" were the same size.  When assembling values out of smaller pieces (as is often done with bytes) unsigned types are easier to work with for all but the uppermost chunk; for any number containing two or more chunks, the extra effort required by making the lower bytes signed will exceed any work saved by making the upper byte signed.