# Behaviour of unsigned right shift applied to byte variable

Tags: java, bit-shift

Consider the following snip of java code

```
byte b=(byte) 0xf1;
byte c=(byte)(b>>4);
byte d=(byte) (b>>>4);
```

output:

```
c=0xff
d=0xff
```

expected output:

```
c=0x0f
```

how?
as b in binary `1111 0001`
after unsigned right shift `0000 1111` hence `0x0f` but why is it `0xff`  how?

Comment: Perhaps the byte is first sign extended to int

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem is that all arguments are first promoted to `int` before the shift operation takes place:

```
byte b = (byte) 0xf1;
```

`b` is signed, so its value is -15.

```
byte c = (byte) (b >> 4);
```

`b` is first sign-extended to the integer `-15 = 0xfffffff1`, then shifted right to `0xffffffff` and truncated to `0xff` by the cast to `byte`.

```
byte d = (byte) (b >>> 4);
```

`b` is first sign-extended to the integer `-15 = 0xfffffff1`, then shifted right to `0x0fffffff` and truncated to `0xff` by the cast to `byte`.

You can do `(b & 0xff) >>> 4` to get the desired effect.

Comment: @PP The absence of unsigned numbers in Java is not a problem (except for integer division, and that will finally be fixed in JDK 8): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397867/port-of-random-generator-from-c-to-java/397997#397997

Answer (score 6):

I'd guess that `b` is sign extended to `int` before shifting.

So this might work as expected:

```
(byte)((0x000000FF & b)>>4)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html):

> The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost position, while the leftmost position after ">>" depends on sign extension.

So with `b >> 4` you transform `1111 0001` to `1111 1111` (b is negative, so it appends `1`) which is `0xff`.

Answer (score 1):

The byte operand is promoted to an int before the shift.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19

> Unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1) is performed on each operand separately. (Binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is not performed on the operands.)

And https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1

> Otherwise, if the operand is of compile-time type byte, short, or char, it is promoted to a value of type int by a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2).

Answer (score 0):

Java tries to skimp on having explicit support for unsigned basic types by defining the two different shift operators instead.

The question talks about unsigned right shift, but the examples does both (signed and unsigned), and shows the value of the signed shift (>>).

Your calculations would be right for unsigned shift (>>>).

Answer (score -1):

byte b=(byte) 0xf1;

if (b<0)

d = (byte) ((byte) ((byte)(b>>1)&(byte)(0x7F)) >>>3);

else

d = (byte)(b>>>4);

First, check the value: 
If the value is negative. Make one right shift, then & 0x7F, It will be changed to positive. then you can make the rest of right shift (4-1=3) easily.

If the value is positive, make all right shift with >>4 or >>>4. It does'nt make no difference in result nor any problem of right shift.