# byte type behavior is not what expected

Tags: java, types, byte, bitwise-operators

In this example:

```
class Test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte mask = 1;
        for(mask <<= 7; mask != 0; mask >>>= 1) {
            System.out.print(mask + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting the output to be -128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1, instead i received an infinite <strike>recursive</strike> loop of -1. If i change the type of the mask variable to be int, the program behaves normally. Could you please explain me why I am having this particular output? Thank you in advance for your time to help me!

Comment: No recursion here, you meant to say infinite loop.

Comment: Actually, it starts like `-128 -64 -32 -16 -8 -4 -2 -1 -1 -1 ...`.

Comment: @Maroun yes infinite loop is what i meant, thank you for correcting me.

Comment: And with both `mask >>>= 1` and `mask >>= 1`, which is strange. As for why, I would also like to know.

Comment: @Gassa at first loop 'mask' will be 1000 0000 that is -128, at the second my intention was to be 0100 0000 that is 64. I used the >>> operator not the >>. Am I mistaken at this as well?

Comment: Googled the cause: `byte` is promoted to `int` before the operation. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948220/behaviour-of-unsigned-right-shift-applied-to-byte-variable.

Comment: @Gassa Thank you, that was very helpful. So far I haven't seen any constructive use of the byte type in java. I admit I am newbie but hey it's byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All byte operations in Java occur by converting a byte into an integer and when the operation finishes it converts the integer back to a byte. The conversion into a byte just removes the highest byte from the int. Hence the int value `0xff00` would be converted into the byte value `0x00`. Now to your example:

When you shift the byte value 1 seven times to the right, you get in the first place the integer value:

```
0x0001
```

which is shift to:

```
0x0080
```

and converted back to the byte value by removing the highest byte:

```
0x80 == 100000000 == -128
```

Now you shift the byte value 1 position to the right, which first converts the byte into the integer:

```
0xff80
```

and then shifts in a 0 to the most significant bit (position 31) which results in:

```
0x7fc0
```

Converted the int value back to a byte by removes the highest byte results in:

```
0xc0 == 11000000 == -64
```

And this continuous til to the byte value

```
0xff == 11111111 == -1
```

and will never end.

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed explanation!