# Why is "int i = 2147483647 + 1;" OK, but "byte b = 127 + 1;" is not compilable?

Tags: java, byte, int

Why is `int i = 2147483647 + 1;` OK, but `byte b = 127 + 1;` is not compilable?

Comment: I have a genuine doubt too: why is the `byte` data type such a pain?!

Comment: it's definitely a design mistake that `byte` is signed instead of unsigned.

Comment: @BoltClock It's only a pain when you don't know how to use it properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397867/port-of-random-generator-from-c-to-java/397997#397997

Comment: @starblue, is there any real-life example where the Java byte type is applicable?

Comment: If there is data that is specified as a byte then use a Java `byte` for clarity, e.g. in parameters. In that case the fact that you can't assign `int` values will even catch some bugs. Or use `byte` to save space in arrays. I wouldn't use `byte` for a single value that just happens to fit in a byte.

Comment: Josh Bloch always mentions that issue. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcY8cYfAEwU around min 12.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Constants are evaluated as ints, so `2147483647 + 1` overflows and gives you a new int, which is assignable to `int`, while `127 + 1` also evaluated as `int` equals to `128`, and it is not assignable to `byte`.

Comment: Actually, today I read some of **Java puzzlers** , including a puzzle just about that... See here: http://www.javapuzzlers.com/java-puzzlers-sampler.pdf - puzzle 3

Comment: The issue is the type `int` due to binary numeric promotion, the value `127` is a red herring.

Comment: I would prefer constants being evaluated with infinite precision and also giving an error on int i = 2147483647 + 1;

Comment: @MByD: As you said "`while 127 + 1 also evaluated as int equals to 128, and it is not assignable to byte.`", does this mean that 50 + 1 will be evaluated as `byte` and hence is assignable to `byte`?

Comment: @10101010 - not exactly. it will be assignable to byte, but first (according to the standard) it will be evaluated as int.

Answer (score 36):

The literal 127 denotes a value of type int.  So does the literal 1.  The sum of these two is the integer 128.  The problem, in the second case, is that you are assigning this to a variable of type byte.  It has nothing to do with the actual value of the expressions.  It has to do with Java not supporting coercions (*).  You have to add a typecast

```
byte b = (byte)(127 + 1);
```

and then it compiles.

(*) at least not of the kind String-to-integer, float-to-Time, ...  Java does support coercions if they are, in a sense, non-loss (Java calls this "widening").

And no, the word "coercion" did not need correcting.  It was chosen very deliberately and correctly at that.  From the closest source to hand (Wikipedia) : "In most languages, the word coercion is used to denote an ***implicit*** conversion, either during compilation or during run time." and "In computer science, type conversion, typecasting, and coercion are ***different*** ways of, implicitly or explicitly, changing an entity of one data type into another.".

Comment: Your code example should probably be byte b = (byte)127 + 1; which is 'Add 1 to a maxed out byte value', your example just turns int value of 128 into a byte value.

Comment: @NKCSS - I don't think you're right, this - `(byte)(127 + 1)` cast 128 (integer) to a byte, while this `(byte)127 + 1` cast the 127 to a byte, but then again to an int, since it's added to 1(int) and you get 128 (int) and error stays.

Answer (score 7):

As an evidence to @MByD:

The following code compiles:

```
byte c = (byte)(127 + 1);
```

Because although expression `(127 + 1)` is int and beyond the scope off `byte` type the result is casted to `byte`. This expression produces `-128`.

Answer (score 3):

JLS3 #5.2 Assignment Conversion

( variable = expression )

In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char or int :

A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

---

Without this clause, we wouldn't be able to write

```
byte x = 0;
char c = 0;
```

But should we be able to do this? I don't think so. There are quite some magic going on in conversion among primitives, one must be very careful. I would go out of my way to write

```
byte x = (byte)0;
```

Comment: as to the question should we be able to... i don't see really anything wrong with `byte x = 0` but then again, I am a C programmer.

Comment: I could maybe see an argument against char c = 0, but why is byte x = 0 wrong?

Comment: It's misleading to untrained eyes, thinking they are assigning a byte 0 to a byte variable. Not much harm in this example, but in general, operating on byte/short/char could get very confusing due to implicit conversions. They are much more complicated than people would think. I want as much clarity as possible in my code, don't introduce any uncertainty for the sake of saving a few key strokes.

Comment: Does a similar rule apply when the narrowing primitive conversion is from long to int, e.g. int i = 1+0L ?  Just asking because your quoted text explicitly leaves that case out.

Comment: @Erwin no, `int i=0L` is illegal.

Comment: :-o    That is most curious language design.

Comment: @ErwinSmout: To the Java Virtual Machine, all numeric expressions are `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`.  Given `byte byteArr[]`, a statement like `byteArr[1] = byteArr[0]` will convert `byteArr[0]` to an `int`, and then store the result to `byteArr[1]` while discarding the upper bits.  An explicit cast to `byte` doesn't really "convert" anything--it masks off the upper bits, leaving the value as an `int`, and then *tells the compiler to allow it to be stored to things of type `byte`*.  If the compiler didn't squawk at an attempt to store an `int` to a `byte`, the runtime wouldn't care.

Comment: Yes but that's the VM, not the language.