# Migrate bitwise operators for unsigned types to java (without unsigned types)

Tags: java, android, c, bitwise-operators, unsigned

I'm migrating an iOS app to Android.

This iOs app uses types like uint32_t. This is an unsigned int 32 which it is not available on Java.

```
uint32_t range is 0 to 4,294,967,295.

int32_t can hold values from –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
```

I have this code in Objective-C:

```
uint32_t vectorRxV1;
UInt16   xxsDas;

[ ... ]

UInt8 CM_L = (vectorRxV1 & 0xBB000000) >> 24;
```

And also:

```
uint32_t vectorTxV0 += ((vectorTxV1<<4) + VectorSelK0) ^ ((vectorTxV1>>5) + VectorSelK1);
```

And also:

```
Uint8 sincroRx = (sincroRx & 0xD9);
sincroRx = (sincroRx | 0xA2);
```

I'm not sure if I use a `long` instead of `uint32_t` (or `int` instead of `UInt8`, the code above will give different value.

**UPDATE**
I have these operators: `>>`, `<<`, `&`, `^` and `|`.

What do you think?

Comment: If you have decided to stay in C, then is this even a question anymore?

Comment: Bitwise operator operates independently of the sign, except for right shift. Check whether the right shift is arithmetic or logical before use.

Comment: @trumpetlicks because shifting left does not sign-extend.

Comment: @nhahtdh - yes but he is trying to use unsigned ints!!!

Comment: @trumpetlicks: I'm not sure what the OP wants - too many questions. I'm talking about using bitwise operator in Java - and how to convert code to work with Java `long` type, which is signed.

Comment: I have updated my question with the operators that I use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397867/port-of-random-generator-from-c-to-java/397997#397997

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to mitigate the absence of unsigned data types, Java introduced the `>>>` operator for shifting right, which does not sign-extend the value being shifted. This is the only bit operation that would suffer from the fact that the number is interpreted as signed.

If you replace all `uint32_t` with `int`, and replace all `>>` operations on "unsigned" values with `>>>`, you will get identical bit patterns in the results of your operations.

Comment: To be clear, `+`, `-`, `*`, `==`, `&`, `|`, `^`, and `<<` are all equivalent for signed and unsigned types.  `/`, `%`, `>>`, `<`, and `>` are not.  (In a pinch, if you need any of the latter operations, Guava's [`UnsignedInts`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInts.html) has methods to substitute for those.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment and answer. So, I only need to change `>>` with `>>>` and use `long` instead of `uint32_t` and `int` instead of `UInt8` to make it works, isn't it?

Comment: @VansFannel Assuming that you are performing bit operations on your unsigned numbers, that's correct. I would use `short` instead of `int` for my 8-bt integer values, because `short` gives you twice the range that you need.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Im not so sure this COMPLETELY answers his question. IF at some point he decides to do a shift LEFT of his vectorRxV1 variable, then a long is a 64 bit value. If the range that he needs is truly an unsigned he may need to mask off the upper 32 bits after he shifts!!!  He has a "[...]" in his code above so I dont know what he does with that variable.

Comment: @trumpetlicks Oops, you're right, `long` is a 64-bit type. I edited the answer to say that it should be `int`, a 32-bit type. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - No problem whatsoever, this is a GROUP learning site. you all have taught me SOOOOO much. :-) Maybe Ill add an answer just for that bit!!!  +1

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I have updated my question with the operators that I use.

Comment: Basically, you're fine using Java's "signed" `int`, you just need to remember than when you print, compare, or divide values, you need to use "unsigned" versions of those things.

Answer (score 1):

@dasblinkenlight is correct with his operators etc...

There is one note however.  A java long is a 64 bit value, so if you truly want 32 bits worth of unsigned and want a true 32 bit shift left using a 64 bit value than the answer look like follows:

```
long myVar;

myVar = 0x00000000FFFFFFFF & (myVar << someAmount);
```