# Convert 4 bytes to an unsigned 32-bit integer and storing it in a long

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to read a binary file in Java. I need methods to read unsigned 8-bit values, unsigned 16-bit value and unsigned 32-bit values. What would be the best (fastest, nicest looking code) to do this? I've done this in c++ and did something like this:

```
uint8_t *buffer;
uint32_t value = buffer[0] | buffer[1] << 8 | buffer[2] << 16 | buffer[3] << 24;
```

But in Java this causes a problem if for example buffer[1] contains a value which has it sign bit set as the result of a left-shift is an int (?). Instead of OR:ing in only 0xA5 at the specific place it OR:s in 0xFFFFA500 or something like that, which "damages" the two top bytes.

I have a code right now which looks like this:

```
public long getUInt32() throws EOFException, IOException {
    byte[] bytes = getBytes(4);
    long value = bytes[0] | (bytes[1] << 8) | (bytes[2] << 16) | (bytes[3] << 24);
    return value & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFL;
}
```

If I want to convert the four bytes 0x67 0xA5 0x72 0x50 the result is 0xFFFFA567 instead of 0x5072A567.

Edit: This works great:

```
public long getUInt32() throws EOFException, IOException {
    byte[] bytes = getBytes(4);
    long value = bytes[0] & 0xFF;
    value |= (bytes[1] << 8) & 0xFFFF;
    value |= (bytes[2] << 16) & 0xFFFFFF;
    value |= (bytes[3] << 24) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    return value;
}
```

But isn't there a better way to do this? 10 bit-operations seems a "bit" much for a simple thing like this.. (See what I did there?) =)

Comment: If the variable you are using is long, then the ALU will always perform the operation on 64 bits.  If the variable is int, the ALU always does operations on 32 bits (and leaves the other 32 bits of the ALU capability unused).  Operations on a byte most likely leave 58 bits of the ALU unused.  These operations always take place in one clock cycle, so not a "bit" of good saying 10 bits are too many.

Comment: Nope, your working implementation is exactly the right approach.

Comment: You don't need the last bitwise and operation in your code above: value |= (bytes[3] << 24) & 0xFFFFFFFF;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea, I don't think there's any obvious improvement.  If you look at the [`java.io.DataInput.readInt` spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readInt%28%29), they have code for the same thing.  They switch the order of `<<` and `&`, but otherwise standard.

There is no way to read an `int` in one go from a `byte` array, unless you use a memory-mapped region, which is *way* overkill for this.

Of course, you could use a `DataInputStream` directly instead of reading into a `byte[]` first:

```
DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("myfile"));
d.readInt();
```

`DataInputStream` works on the opposite endianness than you are using, so you'll need some `Integer.reverseBytes` calls also.  It won't be any faster, but it's cleaner.

Answer (score 5):

A more regular version converts the bytes to their unsigned values as integers first:

```
public long getUInt32() throws EOFException, IOException {
    byte[] bytes = getBytes(4);
    long value = 
        ((bytes[0] & 0xFF) <<  0) |
        ((bytes[1] & 0xFF) <<  8) |
        ((bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 16) |
        ((long) (bytes[3] & 0xFF) << 24);
    return value;
}
```

Don't get hung up on the number of bit operations, most likely the compiler will optimize those to byte operations.

Also, you shouldn't be using `long` for 32-bit values just to avoid the sign, you can use `int` and ignore the fact that it is signed most of the time.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397867/port-of-random-generator-from-c-to-java/397997#397997).

**Update:** The cast to long for the most significant byte is needed, because its most significant bit would otherwise be shifted into the sign bit of a 32-bit integer, potentially making it negative.

Comment: need to use ((long)(bytes[+3] & 0xFF) << 24); for right sign